# CheckedListBox populating a text control

Tags: c#, windows, checkedlistbox

I have a text box that is going to be populated with a comma spereated list that is driven by a CheckedListBox control.

The idea is that as the user checks items off in the list, they will appear in the text field above. I have this working to the point where if I check an item and then click somewhere else inside the control then the text ends up in the textbox. I am capturing the click event on my control.

If I use the item_checked event then the list in the text box isn't updated until I check a second item (at which point in time only the first item that was checked is displayed in the text box.) Is there anyway around this? Reading on MSDN doesn't seem to show any other events that would be applicable.

I'm using .net 1.1.

This is the method that is run on the event trap.

`Private Sub FillCheckedTagsTextBox()`

```
    txtSelectedTags.Text = ""

    Dim tagChecked As Object

    For Each tagChecked In cltTagSelection.CheckedItems

        txtSelectedTags.Text = txtSelectedTags.Text + tagChecked.ToString() + ", "

    Next
```

End Sub

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch 1.1? Is your employer trying to kill you? I'd try to push up to 2.0 if I could.

To double check when you say the "Checked" event do you mean CheckedChanged? In 2.00 this works fine on desktop. Is it a bug in 1.1?

If it is a bug (check your own code first before deciding this! Then check it again!) then I can suggest trying to capture the Leave event which occurs when a control loses focus. Failing this you could databind a business object to the .Checked property and then fire your own event when your value changes. E.G.

```
public class MyValues
{
    private bool _check;

    public bool Check
    {
        get
        {
            return _check;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_check != value)
            {
                _check = value;
                // todo: raise event!
            }
        }
    }
}
```